# Visual Studio ADO.NET missing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I would like to connect my Visual Studio 2013 project (Windows 8.1 app, x86) to an external SQL Server database to get, visualize and set some values. Therefore I found out that I need to use ADO.NET.

Unfortunately the related template in Visual Studio seems to be missing. So I googled that problem and found some solution possibilities (reset visual studio settings and user data, reinstall Visual Studio, run newest version of EFTools,...), but nothing could help me. I tried for hours now...

So what could be the problem here? I have installed VS13 Ultimate from MSDNAA. Why are the templates missing? Is there another easy way to access the external SQL Server database?

Thank you very much!

edit:

It seems to be that a so named "Universal App" doesn't support ADO.NET (for other projects I easily can add an "ADO.Net Entity Data Model". What else can I do to access a SQL Server database? What is the right way in such case?

Comment: You should expose those things from your database that you need in your universal app using a **web service** - these days, most often, that means a REST & JSON based service that any kind of device can attach to and get the data it is supposed to use

Comment: Can I use this WCF project to do this work? Would be the easiest thing or am I wrong? Unfortunaltely I can change nothing on server side [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-access-data-from-5f2602ec#content)

Answer (score 0):

Most convenient way to implement database access would be with EntityFramework as you figured out already. What marc_s meant is that for your app, you cannot implement it directly in this type of the project.

Implement your Data Access Layer in a separate project of Class Library and expose the data using either WCF or WEB API projects (your services layer) that will make use of he DAL. For both Entity Framework and for services there are numerous tutorials all over the internet. When your services are working (and tested!) you just add a reference to your universal app and call the services from there. That way the database access is isolated from the application and all the vulnarable and time consuming logic stays on the server side.

P.S. Services and DAL does not need to be kept in the same machine as the database, however it's recommended to keep it in the same network.